# On compactifications of Lindelöf spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactification, lindelof-spaces

Consider a compact Hausdorff space $X$ and let $A$ be a $G_\delta$ subset of $X$. Then the space $X\setminus A$ must be Lindelöf.

Keeping this in mind, I wonder if the converse is true, that is, if any Lindelöf Hausdorff space X admits a compactification $Y$ such that the remainder $Y\setminus X$ is a $G_\delta$ subset of $Y$. I'm familiar with the Stone-Cech compactification, but I can't see whether the remainder $\beta X\setminus X$ is a $G_\delta$ subset of $\beta X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y$ be any compactification of $X$. If $Y\setminus X$ is a $G_\delta$ subset of $Y$ then $X$ is an $F_\sigma$ subset of $Y$. Since $Y$ is compact this means $X$ is $\sigma$-compact. So for a counterexample let $X$ be a separable metric space which is not $\sigma$-compact, say $X=\mathbb R^\omega$ (Hilbert space) or $X=\mathbb N^\omega$ (the irrational numbers).

Comment: Indeed! So this property characterizes $\sigma$-compact spaces.

Comment: At least if $X$ is a Tychonoff space, so that it has a Hausdorff compactification.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are Lindelöf spaces that are not Čech-complete. E.g. The Sorgenfrey line is such an example.

Comment: Cech-complete spaces are the ones such that $X$ is a $G_\delta$ of $\beta X$. I'm requiring the remainder $\beta X \setminus X$ to be $G_\delta$.

Comment: @AndréPorto  I got a bit confused about the initial fomulation in terms of $X\setminus A$. I immediately got the associaion with Čech-completeness while $\sigma$-compactness was indeed key. Well, the Sorgenfrey line has neither an $F_\sigma$ as a $G_\delta$ remainder, it's a "bad remainder space", in a sense.